# Событие onclick для всех элементов по имени тега или класса

Tags: javascript, click

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с проблемой, что в чистом `JS` есть нюанс, что если ты добивашь событие `onclick` не для `id` а для тега или для класса, то ничего не произойдет – клики по любому из этих элементов будут игнорироваться, а в консоли будет возвращать `что-то там is not a function`.

Пример: Мне надо по клику на каждую кнопку c классом `btn` выводился `alert`, но вот так не сработает:

```js
//Можно пропустить код отсюда
var butt = "<button class='btn'>Click me</button>";




var i;

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
 document.write(butt + "<br/>");
}
//до сюда

document.querySelectorAll(".btn").onclick = function(){
alert("ASPAS");
}
```

Не знаю как сделать, как в jQuery – просто поставил для всего массива `.click(function(){});` и оно для всего применилось.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` возвращает коллекцию элементов, у которой нет свойства `onclick`.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].onclick = function(){
    alert("ASPAS");
  };
}
```

```css
.btn
{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  margin:5px;
  background-color:gray;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn"></div>
<div class="btn"></div>
<div class="btn"></div>
<div class="btn"></div>
```

Comment: Ееее. Спасибо не знал этого.

Comment: а не плохая ли это практика вешать слушателей на пачку элементов) нежели повесить его на какой то общий блок и проверять не является ли кликнутый элемент кнопкой с классом `btn`

Comment: Если я правильно понял **ddeadlink**, то он предложил использовать делегирование событий, и по-моему, это лучший вариант, т. к. он позволяет эффективней обрабатывать изменение внутреннего содержания элемента-контейнера. Более подробное описание - http://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation . Единственное, я бы использовал назначение нужного обработчика для определенного элемента в HTML разметке, а не в коде, как указанно в примере. Исключением, можно считать лишь случай, когда нужно использовать разные обработчики для элементов с одним `className` или `tagName`, но и тут можно найти выход...